# OnNavigatedTo vs Load event

Tags: c#, initialization, windows-phone-7

In several online examples I found this:

```
public partial class ForecastPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    Forecast forecast;

    public ForecastPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

but in others I found the use of the `Load` event like

```
public partial class Person : PhoneApplicationPage
{
  private PersonViewModel _ViewModel;

  public Person()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(SearchView_Loaded);
  }

  void SearchView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     // code here
  }
}
```

I know that `OnNavigatedTo` fires before the `Load` event, but both fire before the UI is drawn into the phone, so my question is **Is there any advantage** in use one method from the other?

Comment: If you are doing a lot of initialization, then you will want to use Loaded as opposed to OnNavigatedTo or else your page may take some time to load.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'd disagree with Tigran.

```
public View()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  personList.ItemsSource = PersonDataSource.CreateList(100);

    Loaded += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine("Loaded");
}

  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
      Debug.WriteLine("Navigated");
  }
```

While jumping forward-backward, output is

> Navigated
>   Loaded
>   Navigated
>   Loaded
>   Navigated
>   Loaded

So, `OnNavigated` is called when page **navigation** is done, but before(during) page controls are loaded, while `Loaded` is called when page is ready and all controls **are loaded**.

Comment: Hmmm...should Tigran's answer have been accepted then? I wonder if this is still true in 8.1

Answer (score 8):

Reading from documentation about `OnNavigatedTo`:

> Called when a page becomes the active page in a frame.

and when we read about `Loaded` event see:

> Occurs when a FrameworkElement has been constructed and added to the
>   object tree.

They are completely different, as page, correct me if I'm wrong, can become `active` more then one time during the lifetime of your application, but constuction of the `FrameworkElement` *usually* happens once.

Comment: A few of the MSFT examples (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff967547(v=vs.105).aspx) put their code in OnNavigatedTo and use a bool in the page constructor to determine if it needs to be executed.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows Runtime, the Loaded event will always fire after OnNavigatedTo (even when pages are being cached by setting NavigationCacheMode.Required). Vitalii is right about that.

According to MSDN:

> In the Windows Runtime implementation, the Loaded event is guaranteed
>   to occur after a control template is applied, and you can obtain
>   references to objects that are created by applying the XAML template.
>
> For app code that uses navigation between pages, do not use
>   Page.OnNavigatedTo for element manipulation or state change of
>   controls on the destination page. The OnNavigatedTo virtual method is
>   invoked before the template is loaded, thus elements from templates
>   aren't available yet. Instead, attach a Loaded event handler at the
>   root of the newly loaded page's content, and perform any element
>   manipulations, state changes, event wiring and so on in the Loaded
>   event handler.

But there is a good reason why you would want to use OnNavigatedTo: it is the only place where you can get the navigation parameters. If you never use navigation parameters, use the Loaded event.