# Data passed to OnNavigatedTo becomes null in main method - Querying ObservableCollection C# UWP

Tags: c#, sql, uwp, observablecollection

I am trying to show just a selection of data from table, no errors show up but the list does not show up (no records are shown).

```
ObservableCollection<Product> DB_List = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        ReadAllProductsList db = new ReadAllProductsList();
        DB_List = db.GetAllProducts();//Get all DB products 

        IEnumerable<Product> query = 
        from d in DB_List
        where d.CatId == 
        /*error here */ currentCategory.CatName
        select d;

        LstView.ItemsSource = query.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();
```

**EDIT**:
I think I narrowed the error here.
When I hardtype the Category.CatName value by using it's exact name instead of `currentCategory.CatName` the list shows up and all products that match the category show up.

So, if I write:

```
where d.CatId == "Tools"
```

All Products from Category `"Tools"` show up.

In my original code I use `currentCategory.CatName` because in another method I pull the Category's Name like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            currentCategory = e.Parameter as CatId;
            NameBox.Text = currentCategory.CatName;
        }
```

And earlier in the code I go like this:

```
**<<<<ERROR HERE I GUESS>>>>>>**
CatId currentCategory = new CatId();
```

EDIT2:

I created Test TextBlock and Test Button. within the Button event I put:

```
TestCategory.Text = currentCategory.CatName;
```

As a result, upon a click, the correct Category Name is displayed.
A mystery.

Here is the CatId Class's code:

```
public class CatId
{
    [SQLite.Net.Attributes.PrimaryKey, SQLite.Net.Attributes.AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string CatName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return CatName;
    }

    public CatId()
    {

    }

    public CatId(string catId)
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        CatName = catId;
    }
}
```

And here is Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    [SQLite.Net.Attributes.PrimaryKey, SQLite.Net.Attributes.AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string CatId { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return CatId;
    }

    public Product()
    {

    }

    public Product(string catId, string productId)
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        CatId = catId;
        ProductId = productId;
    }

}
```

EDIT: Strange behavior on OnNavigatedTo:

What I did I made:

```
CatId currentCategory = new CatId();
```

static.

Now, the first time I navigate to Category's detail page, I get nothing. But when I nagivate back and back to detail's page again I get the records.

For some reason currentCategory remembers the last opened Category's page, and not the current.

currentCategory should represent the CatName on the moment of Navigation, not the last navigatedTo.

SOLUTION???

I placed all the main code from beginning of my question (including code that pulls all products and query that filters data) in OnNavigatedTo method and now list works..

But is this really a solution?

How would this affect my program if I leave this code in OnNavigatedTo?

Is there a chance to leave the code in original place and pull the CatId before it is being nulled?

Comment: d.Id and currentCategory.Name are both strings

Comment: When debugging does `query` have results?

Comment: When debugging no errors show up

Comment: But no records show up

Comment: Then the issue is with your query. Its hard for us to figure out what the exact issue is without seeing the data and values. Does `DB_List` have results?

Comment: Yes, if I remove query all products show up in the list

Comment: Yes. I am sure at 100%

Comment: What is `currentCategory` here?

Comment: It is the string representation of category that must match the Id from query

Comment: As MisterMystery said, there is nothing wrong with the query string itself. Please check there do have records in the `DB_List` that `Id` equal   `currentCategory.Name`. Otherwise you should provide a [mcve], we cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Ok. I will edit my question shortly. I hope you can help me out

Comment: What is the type of `DB_List`?

Comment: DB_List is an ObservableCollection of Product Table.

Comment: The thing is that when I don't use query, "DB_List = db.GetAllProducts();" works and "LstView.ItemsSource = DB_List.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();" returns all rows from the Product Table.

Comment: guys, check my edit please.

Comment: but the Category NameBox (TextBox) gets correct Category Name from OnNavigatedTo.

Comment: I think it's likely that there is something going on with the currentCategory . . . are you absolutely sure that the NameBox and the query string are getting the same data?

Comment: Yes. NameBox gets the correct CategoryName when I navigate to the page.

Comment: Print out the value of `currentCategory.Name` before the query and let us know what it is.

Comment: correct Category's Name is displayed.

Comment: Wow that's really weird. Could you add your `CatId()` class code to the question.

Comment: You are using `Category.Name` in the query but there is no `Name` property in `CatId`. Did you mean to use `CatName` in the query?

Comment: typo. It is indeed CatName. I made error in question. But in the code the two are CatName. So it's not that.

Comment: Please post the Product class

Comment: done. please check the edit.

Comment: check my last edit please.  I passed the currentCategory's value to some test TextBlock within the main method. It is null. TextBlock is being populated only within OnNavigatedTo method..

Comment: The issue might lie in the `OnNavigatedTo` event. Maybe try using the `LoadedEvent` [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403103/onnavigatedto-vs-load-event)

Comment: " OnNavigatedTo: it is the only place where you can get the navigation parameters" isn't it my case as I pass the value of Category?